# Interval in for e-mail sending

Tags: laravel

I made a system for sending e-mail but I need to put a interval in the send, today I only show the sending using an "echo" but if you have a progress it would be even better.
I don't know what the best way to do it when I tried to send with more than 3000 contacts was a timeout, but it remained sending.
I found function sleep, but I don't know if it would be suitable for the current code.

```
$locale = DB::table('email_contact')
            ->where('list_id','=',$list)
            ->get();

            for($i = 0;$i < count($locale);$i++){
                if($creditemail < count($locale)){
                    echo "you not credit!";
                break;
                }else{
                $sender = $locale[$i];
                $sending = $sender[$i]->email;
                $name = $sender[$i]->name;

            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

            try {
                
                //Server settings
                $mail->SMTPDebug = false;
                $mail->isSMTP();
                $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
                $mail->Host = 'host';
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                $mail->Username = 'user';
                $mail->Password = 'pass';
                $mail->SMTPSecure = false;
                $mail->Port = 587;
                //Recipients
                $mail->setFrom('mail@my.com', 'Mail - My');
                $mail->addAddress($sending, $name);     // Add a recipient
                // Content
                $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
                $mail->Subject = $subject;
                $mail->Body    = $text;
                
                $mail->send();

                $number = $i+1;

                DB::table('users')
            ->where('id','=',Auth::id())
            ->decrement('email_credit', 1);

            echo 'Sender: '.$number.'/'.count($locale)."<br>";
        }catch (\Exception  $e){
            echo $e;
        }
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use laravel mailer. You can easily add a delay there and also you can improve the code quality as well. Have a look at the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail

```
$when = now()->addMinutes(10);

Mail::to($request->user())
    ->cc($moreUsers)
    ->bcc($evenMoreUsers)
    ->later($when, new OrderShipped($order));
```